# Binding to service property only via reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider a service:

```
app.service('myService',function(){
    this.strProp = '';
    this.objProp = {
        content: ''
    }
})
```

And a controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,myService){
    $scope.str = myService.strProp;
    $scope.obj = myService.objProp;
})
```

Also consider a markup that binds both scope properties

```
<input type="text" ng-model="str">
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.content">
```

When those values get updated through the view via user input, my service will show only those changes made to the object, while the string property stays empty.

Am I right in assuming that this is caused by the fact that the object is bound via reference and the string is not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats right, in your example `strProp` is bound by value.

> When passing in a primitive type variable like a string or a number,
>   the value is passed in by value. This means that any changes to that
>   variable while in the function are completely separate from anything
>   that happens outside the function.
>
> Passing in an object, however, passes it in by reference. In this
>   case, any property of that object is accessible within the function.

So, probably you have to change you code like this:

```
$scope.someProp = myService;
```

And then pass it into your view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="someProp.strProp">
<input type="text" ng-model="someProp.objProp.content">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Excuse the question, but since I have absolutely no insight when it comes to Angulars interior, why is this? Another user has mentioned that the string property should also be bound by reference "because JS works like this".

Comment: @user2422960 In JavaScript, primitive variables *are not* passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `O'REILLY Angularjs` book we should always use `Object` instead of `primitives` to contain your data.

> Though this `primitive-style model` works in simple cases, for most applications you’ll want to create a model object to contain your data creating a model object will prevent unexpected behavior that could be caused by the prototypal inheritance in `$scope objects`.